# how to print record using report in odoo 11?

Tags: python, odoo

i am unable to print record using report, having error:

```
AttributeError: 'report.my_module.certificate_template' object has no attribute 'get_report_values'
```

Here is code below i am using.

```
class Reports(models.AbstractModel):
_name = 'report.my_module.certificate_template'

@api.model

def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
    report_object = self.env['report']
    report = report_object._get_report_from_name('my_module.certificate_template')
    docargs = {
          'doc_ids': docids,
          'doc_model': report.res_partner,
          'docs': self,  
    }
    return report_object.render('my_module.certificate_template', docargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write the method name "get_report_values". Like the following:

```
    class Reports(models.AbstractModel):
       _name = 'report.my_module.certificate_template'

       @api.model
       def get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
           report_object = self.env['report']
           report = report_object._get_report_from_name('my_module.certificate_template')
           docargs = {
                       'doc_ids': docids,
                       'doc_model': report.res_partner,
                       'docs': self,  
                     }
           return report_object.render('my_module.certificate_template', docargs)
```

So, you just need to change the method name.

I hope this helps you.Thank you.

Comment: still having an error :

/my_module/report/my_report.py", line 11, in get_report_values
    report_object = self.env['report']

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 179, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'report'

Comment: Yes, in that you have to write your module name. For reference, I have edited my last answer. You can see.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return an object like the following:

```
@api.model
def get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
    report = self.env['ir.actions.report']._get_report_from_name('your_module.certificate_template')
    records = self.env['your_module_name'].browse(self.ids)
    return {
        'doc_ids': self._ids,
        'doc_model': report.model,
        'docs': records,
        'data': data
    }
```